# Examples of analytic sets and sets that are not analytic in higher dimensions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I'm trying to solve an exercise from Huybrechts where I must determine whether a certain set in $\mathbb{C}^2$ is analytic. However, the book provides no examples of analytic sets or of sets that are not analytic. I'm having a hard time figuring out this material and think it would be helpful to see a nontrivial example or two. Thank you in advance for your help.

Edit 1: I have noticed now that $
\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is not analytic since for any point $w$ on $|z|=1$, and for any neighborhood $U$ of $w$ and holomorphic function $f$ on $U$, that if $f$ is zero on $U \cap \overline{\mathbb{D}}$  then by the uniqueness theorem, $f$ must be zero on all of $U$, which includes points not in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, hence $\overline{\mathbb{D}} \cap U \neq \{ z | f(z)=0 \}$ for any holomorphic $f$. Furthermore, this result should generalize to closed, proper subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. (Which means there are no analytic sets in $\mathbb{C}$ other than $\mathbb{C}$ itself?)

I am still trying to figure out the intuition for higher dimensions.

Edit 2: Now I understand that the set $X = \{(z_1,...,z_m,0,...,0)| z \in \mathbb{C} \}$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}^n$ for $n>m$. We can show this by noticing that the projection maps $f_{m+1}(z)= z_{m+1}$,...,$f_{n}(z) = z_n$ are holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}^n$. It is then easy to show that $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}^n | f_{m+1}(z)= ... = f_{n}(z)= 0 \} = X$ and hence, for each $x \in X$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ (namely $\mathbb{C}^n$) such that $X \cap V$ is the zero set of a set of functions holomorphic on $V$. However, this example is still quite trivial and I am trying to find more interesting examples.

Comment: Let $(z_n)_{n\geq 0}\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ a sequence of distinct numbers. If it has no accumulation point, then $\{ z_n \ :\ n\geq 0\}$ is an analytic set (it is discrete and so we find nbhs where we just have a singelton). On the other hand, if we have any set $A\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ with an accumulation point, then it is an analytic set iff $A=\mathbb{C}$ (follows from the identity theorem). Any open set in $\mathbb{C}^n$ is analytic (locally we can pick the zero function).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks for your answer. I have now also proven to myself that closed, analytic subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$ cannot contain open sets by the identity theorem. However, I'm still having a difficult time intuiting when a "plane" of dimension $k<n$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ can be analytic. Do you have any pointers of how to think about this?

Comment: In fact we can push the first example a bit. The set $\{ 1/(n+1)\ : \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is analytic (as it is again discrete). However, $\{0\}\cup \{ 1/(n+1)\ : \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not. So the union of analytic sets needs not to be analytic (and neither needs the closure).

Comment: A plane of codimension at least $1$ is (up to rotation and translation) given by $\{(z_1, \dots, z_m, 0, \dots, 0) \ : \ z_1, \dots, z_m\in \mathbb{C}\}$. So you need to ask yourself, whether this is an analytic set or not.

Comment: As complex-analytic diffeomorphisms map analytic sets to analytic sets, also all embedded complex-analytic manifolds can be reduced to the case above.

Comment: I will edit my question to show that I understand that the example you gave is an analytic set.

Comment: This example also contains all complex-analytic embedded manifolds. I am not quite sure what kind of example you are looking for.